# Convert and combine multiple images in one line Imagemagick (windows)

Tags: imagemagick

I have 7 images with same size, orientations, color space.

I am trying convert 6 of them to `LinearGray` and combine every three images to `RGB` (RGB_1 and RGB_2).
After this I need to `Subtract` RGB_1 from the 7th image and `Add` RGB_2 to the result.

```
magick.exe ( AAA.png BBB.png CCC.png -colorspace LinearGray ) -combine RES.tga
```

is working as expected, but

```
magick.exe ( ( AAA.png BBB.png CCC.png -colorspace LinearGray ) -combine ) GGG.png -compose minus_dst RES.tga
```

or

```
magick.exe ( ( AAA.png BBB.png CCC.png -colorspace LinearGray ) -combine ) -compose minus_dst GGG.png RES.tga
```

always creates two outputs, `RES-0.tga` and `RES-1.tga`, where one of these is the combined RGB image and the second is a grayscale version of `GGG.png`.

I even can't go to a next step to `Add` RGB_2 combined image.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: The `-compose minus_dst` just sets the composition method. You still have to do `-composite` right after that to do the actual operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question hasn't had much attention, so I wanted to help you along a bit. One thing you can use to make life easier and processing faster is to use **Magick Persistent Registers** (MPR) which are named lumps of memory where you can create stuff, set it aside with a name and then refer back to it later - very handy for more complicated workflows - and much faster than writing to disk and starting a new process.

So, here's how you can combine your first 3 images to form a single image and set it aside as "left" in an MPR, do the same with the next 3 images, and set them aside as "right" in an MPR, and then recall the two images and place them side-by-side. It is a bit artificial, but it demonstrates what I am suggesting. I also write an intermediate PNG file for debug purposes:

```
magick 1.png 2.png 3.png -combine -write "left.png"  -write MPR:left  +delete ^
       4.png 5.png 6.png -combine -write "right.png" -write MPR:right +delete ^
       MPR:left MPR:right +append result.png
```

Notice also that I didn't need any parentheses because I deleted the first combined image so there was nothing left in the image stack before I added `[4-6].png`

So, getting back to your question, you probably want something more like this:

```
magick 1.png 2.png 3.png -colorspace lineargray -combine -write "RGB1.png" -write MPR:RGB1 +delete ^
       4.png 5.png 6.png -colorspace lineargray -combine -write "RGB2.png" -write MPR:RGB2 +delete ^
       MPR:RGB1 7.png -compose minus_dst -composite ^
       MPR:RGB2 -compose add -composite result.png
```

Of course, you would remove the `-write` of the intermediate, debug images in production code.

You could speed this up a tiny bit by doing the second line first, followed by the first line. If you did that you wouldn't need to save the MPR:RGB1 and reload it because it would already be in the image stack ready for the subtraction, but the difference is probably tiny and this way is nearer to your thought process. And it's already much better than 3 separate commands and three separate processes with intermediate disk files, so let's not worry too much.

Comment: Did i understand you right, that instead of my code where i have all files in memory (working PC have way more than 32Gb RAM) and only missed second -composite to apply command, use MPR and as result slowdown all process?

Comment: After you remove the two debugging `-write RGBx.png` commands, the final `magick` command I suggested should everything you said you want and also be faster than what you had.